# The button is hidden in CSS

Tags: css, web, button, hidden

I have a website where all the buttons work well. The main issue is when I use mobile. On the page of the video courses search, the button was visible early, now it's completely gone. How can I make it appear again in CSS?

Please look at the screenshots for more details...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2fKg.png)

Comment: Please post that is reproducible or at least the URL that is be able to inspect. But post the code is recommend.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first screenshot provided, it appears that the `.stm_lms_courses__archive_filter_toggle` class has `display: none;`

This is the culprit that is hiding the button. You want to remove the `display: none;` or set it to `display: block;` to fix the issue.

You can read more about the `display` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know how can I change it with the code maybe?

Comment: In your CSS file, you want to look for the ```stm_lms_courses__archive_filter_toggle``` class. There might be more than one, so look for the one that has the ```display: none;``` attribute. change that to ```display: block;```.

Comment: If by "change it with the code", you mean changes to the html, then you can add ```style='display: block;'``` in the button's html to make the button visible.

Comment: It seems like it appeared now, but how can I save it? When I try to open it with a phone, it is not shown.

Comment: I just added the screenshot in main post, check it please.